# Installing a Python program

Tags: python

I'm trying to install a python program called sonLib, but I'm not able to pass the unittests. I wonder why, because I think I set the PYTHONPATH correctly in my bashrc...

I tried:

```
1. PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/programs/sonLib
   export PYTHONPATH


2. export PYTHONPATH="home/user/programs/sonLib"
```

Can someone of you show me how to get it to work?

[link for sonLib](https://github.com/benedictpaten/sonLib)

Installing sonLib.

1. Place the directory containing sonLib on your python path. i.e.
   PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:FOO
   where FOO/sonLib is the path to the base directory of sonLib.
2. Compile the C code:
   In sonLib type 'make all' then 'make test' to test the installation

Linking the C libraries: all libraries built are placed in 'sonLib/lib'

error message:

```
cd externalTools && make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/programs/sonLib/externalTools'
cd cutest && make all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/programs/sonLib/externalTools/cutest'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/programs/sonLib/externalTools/cutest'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/programs/sonLib/externalTools'
cd C && make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/programs/sonLib/C'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/programs/sonLib/C'
PYTHONPATH=.. PATH=../../bin:$PATH python allTests.py --testLength=SHORT --logLevel=CRITICAL
ImportError: No module named site
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guys don't know why, but if I `unset PYTHONHOME` the test pass

Answer (score 0):

It says that `"Place the directory containing sonLib on your python path. i.e. PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:FOO where FOO/sonLib is the path to the base directory of sonLib."`.

You declared `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/programs/sonLib.` It should be like this: `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/programs`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to place the sonLib base directory directly in your python path folder. If you have easy_install, the site-package should be the perfect place.